# scrollable body of two headers table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how can I create a table (with HTML, CSS, Javascript/jQuery) that has two headers, one row at the top and one column to the left. Also I need the headers to be fixed and I need to scroll only the content of the table.

Also, I need that the size of my cells to be fixed.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: So what now? Do you expect someone here to just do all the work for you? Your reputation is high enough to know SO doesn't work like that.

Comment: If you want to make the content scroll vertically then your header column should also be made scrollable otherwise the data can be mismatched. Consider this example, both of your headers can not be scrolled, when the user will scroll the body content then `value 1 of row 6` can come in front of `row1`. Whatever you are asking is not practical. If you want to make only the top header fixed then mention it in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the plugin here: http://www.fixedheadertable.com

Just include it in your project and initialize it with this line:

```
$('table').fixedHeaderTable( { fixedColumn: true } );
```

The `fixedColumn` option will give you the fixed second "header" you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment whatever you are asking is not practical, so I will here post for making a table with fixed header.

Make the whole table as you make a normal table, like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
<thead>
<th>Table</th>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
<th>Column4</th>
</thead>
<tr>
<th>Row1</th>
<td>Value1</td>
...............
</table>
```

And add this CSS for your table :

```
thead, tbody{
display : block;
}

tbody{
overflow : auto;
height : 100px;
}

td,th{
width : 60px;
height : 50px;
}

th{
background-color : #000000;
color : #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Hi, implementing your solution really freezed the first two headers, but also shrinked their width. I mean the two header rows are now narrower than the data rows. Can you advise please?